# Can string and variable name be different in queryparam annotation in java?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, query-string

Here is a scenario.

Case1: (@QueryParam("**username**") String **username**)
       URL: example?username=yourname

Case2: (@QueryParam("**username**") String **name**)
       URL: example?username=yourname

In these 2 cases which is correct way of using QueryParam.

When I use Case1, it works, yourname is printed. But when I use Case2, null is printed.

I want to implement Case 2 because of following some coding standards. Means I do not want to change the variable name (which is "String name"). But in URL I have to use "username".

Is there any way of using Case2 scenario for QueryParam.

Adding code(1st edit)
Here is the code which I replicated the issue that I am facing

```
    @RequestMapping (value = "/username1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response username1(@QueryParam("username") String username) {
        System.out.println("Username1 is ==> " + username);
        return Response.ok(username).build();
}

@RequestMapping (value = "/username2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response username2(@QueryParam("username") String name) {
        System.out.println("Username2 is ==> " + name);
        return Response.ok(name).build();
}
```

/username1?username=yourname
Output: Username1 is ==> yourname

/username2?username=yourname
Output: Username2 is ==> null

Thank you

Comment: Case 2 is correct, too. You probably made a mistake when testing it.

Comment: Hey JB Nizet. Thank you for your reply. I have updated the question by adding the code along with the output. Please help me know if I have made any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're doing something wrong: you're using `QueryParam`, which is a JAX-RS annotation, in a Spring-MVC application.

The equivalent Spring annotation is `RequestParam`. JAX-RS and Spring MVC are two different things. You can't just use the annotations of one in the other.

Comment: My bad. Thank you so much for correcting the mistake. Sorry, I am unable to upvote.